# How to put images on the left next to titles in the grouped item page based with dynamic width in windows 8 metro?

Tags: c#, xaml, dynamic, windows-8, windows-store-apps

I am currently developing a windows 8 application using XAML and C#. I developed the grouped items page that generates data groups dynamically. I have a list of social media icons that I need to put next to each group title but aligned on the right depending on the group width, since each group has a certain number of items so its width changes so I can't fix one for all the groups I need it to be taken dynamically. So any ideas? if anyone can provide me with the code that would be very helpful. Thanks!

Comment: Add your code, show us your progress. Add a screenshot